# Hololens gen 1 with unity 2020 and MRTK

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to develop a simple application which has simple cube in it for hololens gen 1 through unity 2020.3.26f1 with Mixed reality tool kit and deploy the application through visual studio 2022 (tried in 2019 too) it works in preview without any errors but with some warnings and visual studio builds the application wihout any errors and deploys to hololens gen 1 but in the hololens i am only seeing a empty tab opening with my application name on it on the side and doesn't even show "Made with unity logo" I tried accessing the document which is too old for the newer version of unity.
Am i doing somehing wrong i follwed so many hololens 2 tutorials because no one posted a article or a video for a hololens gen 1 after 2016/2017 but made it till here.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x5A2.png)

Comment: I have made an app using Unity version 2020.3.24f1 and successfully build it on Hololens 1. Can you please format your question so that it has the problem explained in a more understanding way? I think it should work. It depends on what profiles you have chosen in MRTK and XR Managment settings.

Comment: @holouser are there any details you can share regarding using unity 2020 and hololens 1? I would be very happy to be able to do so but the overarching sentiment from Unity and Microsoft  is that 2020 *does not work* with Hololens 1

Answer (score 0):

Unity 2020 does not support targeting HoloLens (1st gen). These headsets remain supported in Unity 2019 LTS with Legacy Built-in XR for the full lifecycle of Unity 2019 LTS through mid-2022. For more information please see: [Choosing a Unity version and XR plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/choosing-unity-version)

Comment: Oh! thanks by the way can we ue mixed reality feature tool for hololens 1?